# Big raw query to Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have the following query:

```
select users.email, count(login_history.id) actions from users
          left join group_memberships ON group_memberships.user_id = users.id
          left join groups ON groups.id = group_memberships.group_id
          left join organisation ON organisation.group_id = groups.parent_id
          right join login_history ON login_history.user_id = users.id
        where group_memberships.group_id = 564 AND ((MONTH(login_history.created_at) = MONTH(CURDATE()) AND YEAR(login_history.created_at) = YEAR(CURDATE())))
        group by login_history.user_id
```

As I'd like to use scopes I need this query in Eloquent. I could use selectRaw and whereRaw and that should work, however would it be better to use Eloquent: Relationships for the Users model and this query? Is it even possible?

Any input much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of these db operations are well documented [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries). Except for maybe the left joins.
You do that like this (with a callback function):

```
->leftJoin('category_lang', function( $join ) {
   $join->on( 'category_lang.category_id', '=', 'do_hta_dirs.hd_pag_ID' );
   $join->on( 'category_lang.lang_id', '=', 'do_hta_dirs.hd_dID' );
   $join->on( 'category_lang.active', '=', DB::raw( '1' ) );
})
```

Comment: Query builder is an option, but what about [Eloquent: Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships)

Comment: Thanks Thomas, would you mind chatting with me a bit? https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158140/laravel-and-eloquent I'd like to pick your brains a bit :)

Comment: Late comment: relationships are actually just `WHERE IN`s